# Populating UITableView with data from NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I want to populate my `UITableView` with data from my `NSMutableArray` but it is getting an exception.

The exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa2ba880'
```

My cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [callDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    return cell;
}
```

This is the array:

```
Array: (
        {
        callId = 3;
        callKeyword = CALL100;
        callName = "Call to All";
        callNumber = 5908;
    }
)
```

What I want to happen is that the cells in my `UITaleView` will display the data in `callId`, `callKeyword`, `callName` and `callNumber`.

Comment: @Nitin Gohel ha pointed you in the right direction. The problem is that you are trying to put a dictionary into a property which is expecting string value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you `CellDetailArray` Data In `Dictionary` so you can Get Deta From `NSMutableArray` like Bellow:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    NSMutableDictionary *d=(NSMutableDictionary*)[callDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text =[d valueForKey:@"callName"];

    [cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    return cell;
}
```

if you want to show all four value in to your TableCell have to Create customeCell with Four UIlable and Sate Value like:-

`YourLable1.text =[d valueForKey:@"callId"];`

`YourLable2.text =[d valueForKey:@"callKeyword"];`

`YourLable3.text =[d valueForKey:@"callName"];`

`YourLable4.text =[d valueForKey:@"callNumber"];`

Comment: With regards to this: `cell.textLabel.text =[d valueForKey:@"callName"];`, do I really need to do it manually?

Comment: you set manualy like `cell.textLabel.text =[d valueForKey:@"callName"];` becouse your data into NSMutableDictionary pr NSDictionary. if your Array like myarray==(data1,data2,data3) then your First Method working fine.

Comment: You should be calling `objectForKey:`, not `valueForKey:` on the dictionary. Or use modern syntax: `cell.textLabel.text = callDetailArray[indexPath.row][@"callName"];`.

Answer (score 2):

you use below code

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[callDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"callName" ];
```

You are trying access dictionary instead of string. callDetailArray conatins dictionary data. inside the dictionary only strings are available so you must need to access it by using objectForKey

Comment: It works like a charm when using this code. What I want to do is that, displays `callId`, `callKeyword`, `callName` and `callNumber` in different cells.

Comment: you have to create labels as much as you want. and you can use the same the code but keys and label should be different